# How to target multiple people using FB.ui feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to target multiple people using the `FB.ui` (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)? I've tried adding an array as a `to` parameter, but that produces the following error.

[image]

Comment: What are you using FB.ui for – calling what dialog? The Feed dialog, I suppose? AFAIK, you can only pass a single user id in the `to` parameter as a “normal” app developer – to use it with more ids at once, your app has to be whitelisted by Facebook.

Comment: That's saviour. Thank you @CBroe. (might not be an option to everyone, though I didn't know that whitelisting enables this feature)

Comment: @CBroe Whitelisting the app didn't help.

Comment: How did you get it white-listed, and by whom?

Comment: @CBroe By requesting the Client Partner. I've provided more details to Facebook, including a link to this post.

Comment: It is confirmed. Whitelisted or not, this feature is not available; unless, of course, you leave the "to" empty and allow the users to name multiple targets.